# Code Review: Efficient? Will it work?

Tags: javascript

### Clarification

This is part of a script that checks if a user has *changed* and values in a form. If the user attempts to leave the page after changing a value they get alerted via onbeforeunload and are presented with the option to either leave the page or stay.

The tricky part is determining the changed state of a (multiple) select list...which is where this question applies. I just wanted to see if anyone could spot any potential problems with the way it is being done.

Someone mentioned that it may not make sense to always use the default value for the comparisons. However, it does make sense in this case. If the user changes a value and then proceeds to change it back to the original before navigating away from the page they probably don't want a "You've change soemthing on the page, Leave or Stay?" alert popping up.

---

The code below is intended to check a select list (`<select>`) to see if the "selected" attributes are the same as the default "selected" attributes. It should work on multiple-select lists as well as single-option select lists.

The function `IsSelectChanged' should return`true`if the selected option(s) are not the same as the default and`false` if the selected option(s) are the same as the default.

The code:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected">Opt 1</option>
    <option>Opt 2</option>
</select>
<script>
    // the code:
    function IsSelectChanged(select){
        var options = select.options,
            i = 0,
            l = options.length;
        // collect current selected and defaultSelected
        for (; i < l; i++) {
            var option = options[i];
            // if it was selected by default but now it is not
            if (option.defaultSelected && !option.selected) {
                return true;
            }
            // if it is selected now but it was not by default
            if (option.selected && !option.defaultSelected) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // implementation:
    $("select").change(function(){
        doSomethingWithValue( IsSelectChanged(this) );
    });
</script>
```

The code should work both for `select` lists that allow multiple selections/initial-selections and the single-selection variants (as seen above).

Can anyone spot any potential bugs or inefficiencies here? Or know of a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you first pick Opt 2 and get true in your function, then upon the next change, if set back to the default value, do you still want the false? If this is the case then I guess your function might be easier to read if you named it isSelectedChangedSincePageLoad or something like that.

Comment: @Knubo (man, that is hard to type on a QWERTY keyboard), Yah, you got the idea. It should ONLY matter if it matches the default `selected` attributes.

Comment: Sigh, someone just upvoted the "what are trying to accomplish" comment AFTER I made posted the clarification . How can I make things more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're testing for `false && true` or `true && false`, you should just be able to use `!==` since the idea seems to be that you want to `return true` when they don't match.

```
if(option.defaultSelected !== option.selected) {
    return true;
}
```

Also, since the order of the loop doesn't seem to matter here, you should be able to use a `while` loop, which should be a little more efficient.

```
var options = select.options,
    l = options.length;
while ( l-- ) {
   ...
```

This way obviates the need for a comparison.

Comment: @David - You're welcome. I also added a note about using a `while` loop instead. I use those whenever a reverse order loop is acceptable. :o)

Comment: True, the reverse loop make be faster if we have to loop over all objects. However, the first option in a select list is often the default selected option. Of course this is just speculation. Also, check out http://www.vervestudios.co/jsbench/; the benchmark results might surprise you.

Comment: @David - Very good point. I think you're right that the defaultSelected is most often at the top of the list. As such, a forward loop makes sense. And thanks for that link. For me, the reverse `while` was fastest but not by much compared to the next.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I don't know how much more "efficient" it would make it, but you're basically doing an XOR in the loop body (the 2 if statements), so why not use one? IIRC, JS doesn't have an explicit XOR only a bitwise one (more info)[^https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators]. A workaround could be accomplished to simulate an actual XOR using the bitwise ^ by passing it values of either 1 or 0 using the ternary operator, for example:

```
if ((option.defaultSelected ? 1 : 0) ^ (option.selected ? 1 : 0)) { return true }
```

If you are going for brevity (thanks [@some](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36866/some) for the idea, see comments below this answer for details);

```
if (option.defaultSelected ^ option.selected) { return true }
```

would achieve the same effect as the two `if` statements in your code.

Comment: wow, what a unique (to javascript) approach. What is your coding (language) background? +1 for cleverness.

Comment: @amireh: I just tested FF, IE, Opera and Chrome and they all agree: `true ^ true === 0` and `true ^ false === 1`, so there is no need to convert it to numbers before the xor.

Comment: A side note, the two if statements that both exit the loop are what made me think there was a better way. So, thanks!

Comment: @some, are you stalking me?  haha

Comment: @David Murdoch! Yes! Look behind you... Sorry, you weren't fast enough! :)

Comment: @some I could almost swear it didn't work the first time I tried it (was a few years back though), I must have done it wrong then, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @amireh: I just looked it up: you are right that JS only have a bitwise xor. But it's implemented as (pseudo): `return leftSide.GetValue().ToInt32() xor rightSide.GetValue().ToInt32()`. See section 10.11 in ECMA-262 Fifth edition: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Why are you looping through all the options in the selector couldn't you just select the selected one or the defaultSelected one

```
$("select option:selected").doSomething();
$("select option.defaultSelected").doSomething();
```

I don't know what you're wanting to do with that stuff though.

Comment: jQuery (er, Sizzle) most likely loops through all options to determine which are `selected` just as my code is.

`defaultSelected` is not a CSS class; it is a property of an option element.

Comment: however, after looking through the jQuery code, it seems that Safari has mis-reported the default selected property of an option. Using jQuery to return the selected elements may be the best bet. +1